# Why does echo * | rm -f not work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Why does `echo * | rm -f` not work? as per my understanding, `echo *` should list all the files in the directory and pipe should send this list as an argument to the `rm -f` command, which should delete the files. What am I missing?

Comment: Note that `echo *` doesn't list hidden files but `echo * .*` does.

Comment: @scai with `echo .*` you'll also have `.` and `..` which isn't a good idea at all. With `shopt -s dotglob`, `echo *` will expand to all files, including the hidden ones, but not `.` nor `..`; it will be safer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipe sends data to stdin. And not to arguments list. These are two very different concepts.

Arguments are what is in line after command line. Stdin is basically just like a file that is already opened, from which you can read.

Please also note that doing things like this: `echo * | xargs rm -f` is bad idea because it might do weird things in case of files with spaces in names, or with "-" at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to explore all the points you touched.

Answer (score 1):

Pass output of `echo *` as arguments rather than stdin inputs from pipe.

```
rm -f `echo *`
```

Comment: This is very, very bad idea. Consider file named "-r ." Of course it would solve the problem the poster is asking, but doing this is just plain wrong.

Comment: @depesz then `rm -f -- $(echo *)` will do the trick (if you have a smart enough `rm`). Otherwise `rm -f $(echo ./*)` will do.

Comment: @depesz add `--` to solve this. `rm -f -- $(echo *)`

Comment: This solves parameter problem, but still can yield bad results in case of files with spaces in names. Really - there is no reason to use echo, and it will cause pain in any way.